# How I can create tasker app ssid variable?

Tags: android, tasker

I have list wifi ssid. When I connect any ssid, I want set same task. So, I want create list variable (forEach JS analog)
`%WiFi_ssid_list`. Value this variable: `one, two, three`.
How I can do it with `Tasker app` Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a profile that will have a `wifi connected` state trigger and a task where you:

1) `variable set` name `%ssid` value `%WIFII`

2) `variable split` name `%ssid` splitter `"` (your SSID should be stored in variable `%ssid2`)

3) `for` variable `%list_item` items `%WiFi_ssid_list`

4) `if` condition `%list_item` matches `%ssid2`

5) your task here

6) `end if`

7) `end for`